# Vague argument on alpha, beta matrices in Bjorken Drell sec 1.3 on Dirac Equation

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

My question concerns a very vague argument given in section 1.3 (specifically, page 8, right before equation 1.17) in the Bjorken and Drell "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" book. The argument seems to be about some aspects of representation theory regarding the $\alpha_i, \beta$ matrices in the ansatz (Eq. 1.13) for the Dirac equation. That equation 1.13 reads (page 6):

> We follow the historic path taken in 1928 by Dirac in seeking a relativistically covariant equation of the form $i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = H\psi$. Since such an equation is linear in the time derivative, it is natural to attempt to form a hamiltonian linear in the space derivatives as well. Such an equation might assume a form:
> \begin{equation}
> i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = \frac{\hbar c}{i}\left(\alpha_1\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \alpha_2\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} + \alpha_3\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z} \right) + \beta m c^2\psi = H\psi \ \ \ \text{(Eq. 1.13)}.
> \end{equation}

The authors go on to analyze the coefficients they've introduced in this ansatz, arguing that they shouldn't be numbers. Henceforth, I personally am going to occasionally refer to $\beta$ as $\alpha_4$, for convenience. Anyway, the authors go on to argue that these shouldn't be hermitian matrices and that all four should the obey anti-commutation relations $\{\alpha_i, \alpha_j \} = 2\delta_{ij}$ for $i,j=1,2,3,4$, and that each of the four can only have eigenvalues that are real numbers of unit absolute value, and that each matrix has vanishing trace, and that this implies that each matrix has an equal number of +1's and -1's eigenvalues so that their sum (the trace) vanishes. Therefore, each matrix can only be $N\times N$ for even values of $N$. That is all perfectly sensible. I have no problem with any of that. My question is about their argument for why $N=2$ is impossible, which they then use to say that $N=4$ is the smallest number of dimensions that they Dirac equation can exist in.

Here is the argument they provide on page 8, right before Eq. 1.17:

> The smallest even dimension, $N=2$, is ruled out, since it can accommodate only the three mutually anticommuting Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ plus a unit matrix.

What does that mean? I don't understand what they even purport to mean in that argument, let alone why it definitively shows that $N=2$ is ruled out.

In case it's useful, I'll provide what they write in the sentences immediately following the above quote.

> The smallest dimension in which the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$ can be realized is $N=4$, and that is the case we shall study. In a particular explicit representation the matrices are
> \begin{equation}
> \alpha_i = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma_i \\\ \sigma_i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \beta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \text{(Eq. 1.17)},
> \end{equation}
> where the $\sigma_i$ are the familiar $2\times2$ Pauli matrices and the unit entries in $\beta$ stand for $2\times2$ identity matrices.

I'll make some other observations that may be relevant to my question here.

Fact 1: The four $\alpha_i$'s are linearly independent, which is very easy to prove. (Proof: Assume they are linearly dependent, then they can be linearly combined to zero, with at least one nonzero coefficient. If that coefficient is next to $J$th matrix, then take the anticommutator of that linear dependence relation with $\alpha_J$ (i.e., act with $\{\alpha_J,\cdot\}$ on the linear dependence relation equation). This implies that nonzero coefficient is zero. Contradiction.)

Fact 2: The real vector space of 2 by 2 hermitian matrices is four-dimensional and the Pauli matrices along with the identity constitute a basis for it.

Fact 3: The real vector space of TRACELESS 2 by 2 hermitian matrices is three-dimensional and the Pauli matrices constitute a basis for it.

Ok, now, what do Bjorken and Drell mean when then say (regarding the four $\alpha_i$'s) that "The smallest even dimension, $N=2$, is ruled out, since it can accommodate only the three mutually anticommuting Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ plus a unit matrix."?

Comment: Write down an arbitrary $2×2$ matrix. Demand it anti-commute with the pauli matrices as specifed. You will find no solutions. For other parts of the argument, keep in mind the identity will commute with everything, so it doesn't have the algebraic properties we want.